# Weekly Time schedule range between days

Tags: sql-server, time, range, schedule

I have a weekly schedule set from Friday evening **2011-05-27 18:00** to Monday morning 
**2011-05-30 06:00**. This schedule executed on every week starts from **2011-05-27**. How we can identify an event time (2011-06-06 19:00) falls between this weekly schedule ?

## UPDATE

```
ID    StartTime         EndTime            Recurrence  TimeDifferenceInSeconds
1     2011-05-27 18:00  2011-05-30 06:00   1           216000
```

Here recurrence is every one week.

Regards,

Greepty

Comment: You need to give more information about how the data is stored (table structure, etc.)

Comment: @tofutim The table structure as follows ID,StartTime,EndTime,Recurrence,TimeDifferenceInSeconds

Comment: Your question confuses me. Does you schedule start the 27th or the 30th? 27th is a Wed and 30th is a Monday. Are you saying that you want to schedule stuff to happen every Wed - Mon, and therefore wants to check if a date falls on a Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun or Mon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach to this problem:

1. Get the number of whole weeks between the given date/time and `StartTime`.
2. Add the number of weeks to `StartTime` to obtain the latest start time.
3. Calculate the difference between the latest start time and the given date/time.
4. Check if that difference is less than `TimeDifferenceInSeconds`.

And this is how it could be implemented:

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedules
WHERE StartTime < @Date AND TimeDifferenceInSeconds >
  DATEDIFF(ss, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, StartTime, @Date) / 7, StartTime), @Date)
```

This returns all the schedules that `@Date` falls on.

A more reader-friendly version:

```
WITH NewSchedules AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    NewStartTime = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, StartTime, @Date) / 7, StartTime)
  FROM Schedule
  WHERE StartTime < @Date
)
SELECT *
FROM NewSchedules
WHERE TimeDifferenceInSeconds > DATEDIFF(ss, NewStartTime , @Date)
```

Comment: **Hi,Thanks for the above workout which is indeed an answer for the issue i had posted,but a slight change was needed in where condition to match the time criterion to as-SELECT * FROM NewSchedules WHERE @Date between NewStartTime and dateadd(second,TimeDifferenceInSeconds,NewStartTime). **

Comment: @user779291: I see. My intention was to build the condition so as to allow the query optimiser to employ indexes, if possible. Still, your version is intuitively clearer, no doubt. On a different point, with your condition a row would be selected if its `EndTime` exactly matched `@Date`. Well, it's up to you, of course, but based on the actual timestamps in your example I assumed that `EndTime` was the time when the schedule was *no longer* valid. That's why I used `TimeDifferenceInSeconds > …` in my solution instead of `TimeDifferenceInSeconds >= …`. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to check if a date will fall between a Wed & Mon.

In that case you can simply do a `SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '6-Jun-2011')` and if that falls on one of the days you have the answer, you will just have to check the time component then.